# Simple SPA (Single Page Application) implementation with hash change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, single-page-application

I am making an app which lets a user do something on page A. However, I want to include a function which links him to page B, and after completing the activity on B, links him back to A with his page A progress in tact. Currently, after linking to page B and then back to A, all of the progress on page A is gone and back to 0. How would this be accomplished?

Comment: store the data in a global variable?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage OR https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: You can use to AJAX to do your job which you're doing on page B instead of moving to page B. Thereby, keeping the progress of page A intact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple **SPA implementation** listening to `#hash` change follows,

```js
$(window).on('hashchange', routePage);

function routePage() {
  var pageName = (window.location.hash) ? window.location.hash : "#page1";
  $('div.pages').hide(); // Hide all pages
  $(pageName).show();    // Show the current page 

  /* switch for page specific functions, not used now */
  switch(pageName) {
    case '#page1':
      alert('Go to Page1');
      break;
    case '#page2':
      alert('Go to Page2');
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
div.pages *{
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
div.pages a, div.pages h4 {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgray;
} 
div.pages a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- First Page -->
<div id="page1" class="pages">
      <h4>Post your comment</h4>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
      <textarea name="comments" placeholder="Your comments"></textarea>
      <a href="#page2">Submit</a>
</div>  
<!--Second Page-->
<div id="page2" class="pages" style="display:none;">
      <b>Success!</b>
      <p>Your comments will be published soon...</p>
      <a href="#page1">Edit your comment</a> 
</div>
```

For detailed SPA implementation using **JavaScript frameworks**, checkout TodoMVC

http://todomvc.com/

Comment: Hi I have tried this out and I think that this is what I am looking for. However upon attempting to adapt your code to my app, I find that when moving back to page A some of the elements are missing. Might you have any idea as to why this is so? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Nevermind, realised it was because of     $('div').hide(); , thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Updated & added a class for page wrapper div

Answer (score 0):

you can save data from page A using any storage mechanism like session or local storage, whatever is feasible to you. When you come back from page B you can pre-filled all the data. You can remove the data from storage when you finished with the process.